# Insert attributes names according to language with polylang programmatically

Tags: php, multi-language, wp-update-post, plugin-polylang

This is my problem. I try to insert in _product_attributes meta_value field the names of each language. When I print out my query, I am getting only the products in the right language, so theoretically I should have my update_post_meta _product_attributes only work with the correct language, but this is not the case. I will then do the same thing for the meta_values but I need this to work first.
This works sometimes which leaves me even more perplexe.
Here is my code for one language (French). Any and all help appreciated.

```
global $wpdb;
$args = array(
 'posts_per_page'   => -1,
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'lang' => 'en'
```

);

```
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) :
 while ($query->have_posts()) :
    $query->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $sku = get_post_meta($post_id, '_sku');
    print("<pre>" . print_r($sku, true) . "</pre>");
     $languagechoice = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'language', true);
      $sku = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_sku', true);

        echo "&nbsp;".$languagechoice."<br>";
        $thedata = Array('references-en' => Array(
            'name' => 'References',
            'slug' => 'references-en',
            'value' => '0',
            'is_visible' => '1',
            'is_variation' => '1',
            'is_taxonomy' => '0'
        ));
        update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_product_attributes', $thedata);
    
   endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```